# Mystery: Slow delete in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I have a SQL table with 29 columns and 3000-4000 rows. It has a few spatial fields (2 geometry and 1 geography) but otherwise nothing special.

Deleting a single row from this table now takes about 1000 ms, both in production and development environments.

```
Delete from AdminDivisions 
where AdminDivisionID=(Select top 1 AdminDivisionID from AdminDivisions)
```

[image: screenshot 1]

Here's what I've tried (in a dev environment):

- I've made a clone of the table and painstakingly recreated all of its triggers, foreign keys, constraints, and indexes. Deleting a row from the clone is instantaneous.

  ```
   Delete from _ad
   where AdminDivisionID=(Select top 1 AdminDivisionID from AdminDivisions)
  ```

[image: screenshot 2]

- I've deleted all triggers, foreign keys, constraints, and indexes from the original table. Deleting a row from the stripped-down table still takes around 1000 ms on average.

What could I try next?

---

#### Update 1

Here's the execution plan ([full size here](https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/0/AADRGYl1nn4FEdW89e3E-i0SsKOiDPUKCXYBJWOoCDKtZA/12/110744332/png/2048x1536/3/1387148400/0/2/execplan.png/Eiq07g0ArIEpk8BZDo9nIShVjICvHppwQCHQ1Ea8sbA)). It is the FKs referencing this table - and the table's own PK index. Still not sure where to go from here.

[image]

#### Update 2

@Martin: Here is the output with SET STATISTICS IO ON:

```
Table 'Instances'. Scan count 1, logical reads 12, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Locations'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'AwardsAdminDivisionsXtab'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'IndicatorResultComments'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'IndicatorResults'. Scan count 1, logical reads 35958, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Transactions'. Scan count 1, logical reads 155, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'LogicCheckViolations'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'AdminDivisions'. Scan count 1, logical reads 14, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 1, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'AspNet_SqlCacheTablesForChangeNotification'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Comment: What does top 1 mean without an order by? Also what is it actually waiting on (e.g. see wait_type in sys.dm_exec_requests)? If you're going to do that why not just say `DELETE TOP (1) dbo._ad;`? Also note that this will likely cause a table scan when you go to drastic measures like dropping all indexes (including the clustered).

Comment: Show the execution plan. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan

Comment: And in addition to the requests above it would also be interesting to see the output of `SET STATISTICS IO ON;` after deleting a row.

Comment: Do you have an index (possibly a clustered index) on `AdminDivisionID`? Also: have you had a look at updating the table's statistics?

Comment: Do you have FKs referencing a PK/UQ (unique key) within `AdminDivisions` ? Maybe those FKs aren't indexed thus causing scans.

Comment: You need to test with a copy of whole database but not only one table. May be you have cascading deletion set and this results in delay.

Comment: @Aaron The `Select top 1 AdminDivisionID from AdminDivisions` is just to isolate a single row - didn't know about `Delete Top (1)`. At any rate the result is the same if I give it a constant AdminDivisionID to delete.

Comment: How long does "Select top 1 AdminDivisionID from AdminDivisions" take? Are you sure it's the "delete" that's taking the time, and not the select statement?

Comment: How many rows in `Transactions` and `IndicatorResults`? They both have scans not seeks. Also output of `SET STATISTICS IO ON;` please?

Comment: @Neville - it take same amount of time if I give it a constant PK to delete.

Comment: So looks like you need to add an index to `IndicatorResults` then to allow the FK validation to be more efficient. Also probably wouldn't hurt to add the missing index on `Transactions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess because I don't have enough information:

1. Maybe the target table (`AdminDivisions`) is a parent table and there is a FK referencing the PK or a UQ (unique key) of / within `AdminDivisions` and
2. This FK has a `ON DELETE CASCADE` option and
3. This FK isn't indexed.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ParentTable(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.ChildTable(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentID INT NOT NULL 
        REFERENCES dbo.ParentTable(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO
DELETE dbo.ParentTable
WHERE ID = 1;
```

The execution plan for `DELETE dbo.ParentTable ...` statement **before** creating an index on `dbo.ChildTable(ParentID)` :
[image]

The execution plan for `DELETE dbo.ParentTable ...` statement **after** creating an index on `dbo.ChildTable(ParentID)` (`CREATE INDEX IX1 ON dbo.ChildTable(ParentID);`) :
[image]

Comment: Thanks Bogdan and all others who commented. In your list above #1 and #3 are true (there's no cascading delete) but it was the foreign key constraint (with no index) that was slowing things down dramatically.